# How to replace all spaces present in a string with underscore using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string with spaces separating words. I want to replace all the spaces in the string with underscore. Please tell me any small code for that because my solution is taking too much space.
Example : 'Divyanshu Singh Divyanshu Singh'
output : 'Divyanshu_singh_Divyanshu_Singh'

Comment: `yourString.replace(/\s+/g, "_")`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this one:

```js
    var str = "Divyanshu Singh Divyanshu Singh";
    var res = str.replace(/ /g, "_");
    console.log(res);
```

Use, / /g is a regex (regular expression). The flag g means global and causes all matches to be replaced.

Comment: will only replace the first match.

Comment: `/ /` won't find multiple spaces in a row. It should be: `/\s+/g`.